# Does the Query Optimizer Prefer to Query on Constants before Columns?

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, query-performance

I think I have found the answer for this already but I am hoping to get some additional perspective.

Assume we are `JOIN`ing two tables together on a shared column and each table then has a different `column` we are going to do a `Constant` search on.  When we build an `index` to support the query, for each table do we want to put the `JOIN`ing `column` first, or the `Constant` `column` first?  I am thinking now it is the `Constant` `column` first.  When I look at a query plan for a different query that prompted this question, it appears it tries to create a subset of each table and then `JOIN` them together.  Instead of `JOIN`ing the two tables togeather and filtering down from there.

EX: Joining Shipments to Customers where Shipment is Shipped and Customer is Active

```
SELECT [Columns]
FROM Shipment S
   INNER JOIN Customer C
      ON S.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE S.IsShipped = 1
AND C.IsActive = 1
```

I am thinking the two best indexes to use are below.  Because the `Query Optimizer` would prefer to scan the `Constant` first then `JOIN` on the 2nd `column` instead of `JOIN`ing the two `tables` together and filtering on the `constant` after that.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IsActive-CustomerID] ON [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [IsActive] ASC,
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IsShipped-CustomerID] ON [dbo].[Shipment]
(
    [IsShipped] ASC,
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Instead of:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CustomerID-IsActive] ON [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [CustomerID] ASC,
    [IsActive] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CustomerID-IsShipped] ON [dbo].[Shipment]
(
    [CustomerID] ASC,
    [IsShipped] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no other queries of concern, the general answer is that you want more selective criteria in the leading columns of the index (note that selectivity here is in relation to the predicate rather than a measure of how unique the particular values in the column are).  In general, you want the optimizer to eliminate as many rows as possible as quickly as possible.

Assuming that `CustomerID` in `Shipment` is `NOT NULL` and has a foreign key to `Customer`, meaning that the `inner join` is guaranteed not to eliminate any rows from `Supplier`, then `s.IsShipped = 1` is the only selective predicate and it would make sense for it to be the leading column.  If, on the other hand, the `inner join` was more selective (imagine that someone moved rows from `Customer` to `Customer_Archive` periodically and `Shipment` could join to either of those tables), it would make sense to have `CustomerID` as the leading column.

Comment: For the purpose of this question I am more trying to understand some of the under-workings of the query analyzer.  If we assume that 98% of the records in `Shipment` have `IsShipped = 1` and 98% of records in `Customer` have `IsActive = 1`. That would mean `CustomerID` is more selective by a lot.

Comment: @KirkSaunders - `CustomerID` would be more selective if fewer than 98% of the rows in `Shipment` had a matching `CustomerID` in `Customer`.  The most selective predicate is the one that eliminates the largest fraction of rows.  If half the rows get eliminated via the join, you'd generally want the join to happen first and the `CustomerID` to be the leading column.  If doing the join eliminates 0 rows, you'd want `IsShipped` and `IsActive` to be the leading columns.

Comment: When I look a query plans (for a different query that prompted this question) it appears to me the query analyzer tries to create the subset of each table (`SELECT [Columns] FROM Shipment WHERE IsShipped = 1` and `SELECT [Columns] FROM Customer WHERE IsActive = 1`) and `JOIN` them together after that.  Presumably an index leading with `CustomerID` can't be used for generating those two subsets, but could be used for the `JOIN`.  Where an index leading with the "flag" `column` would be able to be used for building the Subset and for the `JOIN`. Does that make sense or am I off?

Comment: @KirkSaunders - Yes, it sounds like the optimizer expects the `IsActive` and `IsShipped` predicates to be more selective than the join so it is executing them first.  That seems reasonable given these two tables (and making reasonable assumptions about the data).  Given a different pair of tables where the join eliminated a substantial fraction of rows, it would likely make more sense to do the join first and then filter.